# how to set multi condition in one constrains in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

how i can set multi constrain for example table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS objects_menagers(

id                 SERIAL
id_application     INT  NOT NULL  REFERENCES applications (id)   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
id_mem             INT  NULL      REFERENCES mem (id)            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
id_hdd             INT  NULL      REFERENCES hdd (id)            ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
id_model           INT  NULL      REFERENCES model (id)          ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

)
```

i try co set this constrain for each column: id_mem, id_hdd and id_model.

```
CHECK (
       id_model > 0 
       AND id_mem IS NULL 
       AND id_hdd IS NULL

       OR  id_mem > 0       
       AND id_model IS NULL
       AND id_hdd IS NULL

       OR  id_hdd > 0       
       AND id_model IS NULL     
       AND id_mem IS NULL
      );
```

when i try:

```
   INSERT INTO objects_menagers (id_application ,id_model) VALUES (1, 7);
   INSERT INTO objects_menagers (id_application ,id_mem) VALUES (1, 6);
   INSERT INTO objects_menagers (id_application ,id_hdd) VALUES (1, 1);
```

and too:

```
   INSERT INTO objects_menagers (id_application ,id_model,id_mem,id_hdd) VALUES (1, 7, NULL, NULL);
   INSERT INTO objects_menagers (id_application ,id_mem,id_model,id_hdd) VALUES (1, 6, NULL, NULL);
   INSERT INTO objects_menagers (id_application ,id_hdd,id_model,id_mem) VALUES (1, 1, NULL, NULL)
```

i got:

```
 ERROR:  new row for relation "objects_menagers" violates check constraint "objects_menagers_check2"
 DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 1, 7, null, null).
```

**Okey - Dear Tomas check this code:**

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS objects_menagers (
     id                 SERIAL      PRIMARY KEY
    ,id_application     INT         NOT NULL                                        
    ,id_model           INT         NULL        CHECK (id_model > 0 
                                                       AND id_mem IS NULL 
                                                       AND id_hdd IS NULL
                                                       OR id_mem > 0 
                                                       AND id_hdd IS NULL 
                                                       AND id_model IS NULL
                                                       OR  id_hdd > 0 
                                                       AND id_model IS NULL 
                                                       AND id_mem IS NULL)      

    ,id_mem              INT        NULL        CHECK (id_mem > 0 
                                                       AND id_hdd IS NULL 
                                                       AND id_model IS NULL
                                                       OR  id_model > 0 
                                                       AND id_mem IS NULL 
                                                       AND id_hdd IS NULL
                                                       OR  id_hdd > 0 
                                                       AND id_model IS NULL 
                                                       AND id_mem IS NULL)      

     ,id_hdd              INT       NULL         CHECK (id_hdd > 0 
                                                        AND id_model IS NULL 
                                                        AND id_mem IS NULL
                                                        OR  id_mem > 0 
                                                        AND id_hdd IS NULL 
                                                        AND id_model IS NULL
                                                        OR  id_model > 0 
                                                        AND id_mem IS NULL 
                                                        AND id_model IS NULL)       
   );
   INSERT INTO objects_menagers (id_application ,id_model) VALUES (1, 7);
   INSERT INTO objects_menagers (id_application ,id_mem) VALUES (1, 6);
   INSERT INTO objects_menagers (id_application ,id_hdd) VALUES (1, 1);
```

Comment: I don't get any errors, you should post exact sequence of commands leading to error.

Comment: chceck updated code above

Comment: Why do you repeat the `CHECK` constraint for every column? You can write one table constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your conditions in parens - you're getting an order of operations error. You want

```
check ((id_hdd > 0 and id_model is null and id_mem is null)
         OR (id_hdd is null and id_model > 0 and id_mem is null)
         OR (id_hdd is null and id_model is null and id_mem > 0))
```

Also, like Igor said, there's no reason to repeat the constraints for every column - one table constraint will suffice.